# Overriding a method in a subclass of a generic type passed to a list

Tags: c#

For a class, we have a Card class that as you can image, has 2-A for the different suits.  Next comes a deck class that is defined as

```
public class Deck : List<Card>
```

Card has a method

```
public int GetValue() {
      get
            {
                if (ValidFaceValues.Contains(FaceValue)) // ValidFaceValues is basically a List<string> of 2-A
                {
                    return ValidFaceValues.IndexOf(FaceValue) + 2;
                }
                return 0;   // unknown value
            }
}
```

So this method for J (Jack) returns 11, Q (Queen) returns 12, etc.

What I was wondering, is since Deck has to be a subclass of List, is there any way to change the GetValue() method by overriding it somehow so in my BlackJack game, J, Q, K are all treated as 10?  Thanks.

Comment: That doesnt compile - methods dont have get accessors, properties do.

Comment: Also, subclassing `List<T>` is usually *not* what you want to do. You're better off just making your `Deck` class be composed of a list.

Comment: You mean create IDeck that exposes GetValue and use that in your BlackJack game that inherits from Game, could you add Game to Deck relationship code.

Comment: Agree With @dcastro public class Deck { private List<Card> _deck;} is the way you want to start.

Comment: Reason being: don't mix domain (a deck) with infrastructure (a list). If later you decide a deck should behave as a `Stack<T>` of cards, you're screwed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to make `GetValue` virtual and subclass `Card`:

```
public glass BlackjackCard : Card
{
    public static readonly String[] RoyalFaceValues = new [] {"J", "Q", "K"};
    public override int GetValue() 
    {
        if(RoyalFaceValues.Contains(FaceValue)) return 10;

        return base.GetValue();   
    }
}
```

Since you don't show how `Deck` is used (how is it filled?) I can't say whether other changes would be necessary, but I would consider NOT subclassing `List<Card>` - rather implement `IEnumerable<Card>` and storing the list internally.  That way you can change the data structure later without changing the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use some kind of Dictionary and a subclass of Card called BlackJackCard :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Card
{
    protected Dictionary<string, int> ValidFaceValues;

    private string FaceValue;

    public Card(string FaceValue)
    {
        ValidFaceValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        ValidFaceValues.Add("J", 11);
        ValidFaceValues.Add("Q", 12);
        ValidFaceValues.Add("K", 13);

        if(ValidFaceValues.ContainsKey(FaceValue))
        {
            this.FaceValue = FaceValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        int value = 0;
        ValidFaceValues.TryGetValue(FaceValue, out value);
        return value;
    }
}

public class BlackJackCard : Card
{
    public BlackJackCard()
    {
        ValidFaceValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        ValidFaceValues.Add("J", 10);
        ValidFaceValues.Add("Q", 10);
        ValidFaceValues.Add("K", 10);

        if(ValidFaceValues.ContainsKey(FaceValue))
        {
            this.FaceValue = FaceValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```